# Copy Nexus Repo to GitLab Registry

Tags: gitlab, integration, nexus, data-migration

Initial State:

- A GitLab instance with many projects;
- GitLab projects have pipelines that depend on many binaries, including Docker images
- All these binaries and images exist in a local OSS instance of Nexus (NXRM3) in hosted or group repos of various formats (docker, maven, raw, and so on) or remote repos proxied by the repos in this Nexus.

Target State:

- Content of the GitLab and Nexus is transferred into a GitLab in a way that allows the pipelines to run after trivial modifications, like changing URLs from Nexus to GitLab binary registries.

Challenge:

- What approach to automate that could be more effective (less coding, testing, etc.) than  a custom app/script that uses Nexus REST API to "walk" through Nexus, create a corresponding registry in GitLab (using the GitLab API), pull all artifacts from the Nexus repo and then push them into the created GitLab registry?

NOTE:

- Properly mapping Nexus repo type to GitLab is a separate challenge.
- Properly reproducing Nexus repo taxonomy in GitLab is a separate challenge.
- Properly transfer Nexus repo permissions to GitLab is a separate challenge.

Comment: we decided internally to only migrate needed artifacts, like a clean up. Therefor we migrated each project after each other and wrote a gitlab ci pipeline to fetch from nexus and upload to gitlab. This way, we also cleanup our artifact storage a little bit.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner do you have a gitlab-ci example for that ? I want to do it for Docker images and Maven artifact, but I don't know exactly how to proceed. I think I'm going to do it with a script (in Python probably), but I'm looking for better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a script to do the following:

1. Script that lists Docker images stored in a  Docker repo of the aforementioned Nexus instance.
2. Script that pulls a  docker image from the aforementioned Nexus repo of Docker format and pushes it into the Docker registry on a local host.
3. Script that pulls the aforementioned Docker image from the local Docker registry and pushes it into the aforementioned GitLab project Docker registry.